# Group list by key [R]

Tags: r, list

I have a list like :

```
mylist <- list("key 1" = 1,
           "key 1" = 2,
           "key 1" = 3)
mylist
> mylist
$`key 1`
[1] 1

$`key 1`
[1] 2

$`key 1`
[1] 3
```

And I would like my final list to look like this:

```
$`key 1`
[1] 1 2 3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unlist

```
mylist <- list("key 1" = 1,
               "key 1" = 2,
               "key 1" = 3)

mylist2 <- list("key 1" = unlist(mylist,use.names=FALSE))

mylist2
# $`key 1`
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Edit: a general solution if you have several keys:

```
mylist <- list("key 1" = 1,
               "key 1" = 2,
               "key 1" = 3,
               "key 2" = 4,
               "key 3" = 4,
               "key 3" = 4,
               "key 4" = 4)

mylist2 <- tapply(unlist(mylist,use.names=FALSE), names(mylist),c)

# > mylist2
# $`key 1`
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $`key 2`
# [1] 4
# 
# $`key 3`
# [1] 4 4
# 
# $`key 4`
# [1] 4
```

Comment: Extending this approach we can get a more general solution: `mylist2 <-
 lapply(unique(names(mylist)), function(x) unlist(mylist[names(mylist) %in% x], use.names = FALSE)); names(mylist2) <- unique(names(mylist))`

Comment: I added the general approach

Comment: Yes, it's perfect! Thanks !